# What is the easiest way to disable a form but keep it readable?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have my form fields in a Panel which, if a read-only version is required, I set Enabled = False on the Panel. This was quick and dirty and the results are mostly dirty, mostly in IE. Can't scroll through large ListBoxes. Multi-line TextBoxes only show the first few lines. There's some funky styling to disabled Labels.

Do you have any ideas as to how to disable an entire form, letting the user read the data, visually indicating that it is disabled (gray input or text in place of input), but to the server keep the control disabled so it's not loading any data that could be manipulated by enabling fields by nefarious means.

(Also, I'm hoping I don't have to add a label corresponding to each data field.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove all the buttons and use jQuery to change the background color on all inputs.  This would be a quick and easy solution.

```
$(':input').addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: I think my best option is going to be something like this. I need to selectively disable certain form fields. I suppose I could check the WebControl type and add a class / javascript handler to it to indicate to the user that he's not able to edit this field.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your fields assigned the readonly attribute, ie:

```
<input type="text" name=myText value="Enter Your Name" readonly>
```

This can easily be done with js but is more robust if done right in html.

You could also disable or even remove the submit button.

Comment: It's a small thing, but it should be `readonly="readonly"`. Some browsers will not support the shorthand. It should also be noted this only works for `input="text/password"`

Comment: It's actually pretty bad. Major Google fail. My bad ;) +1'ed for setting me straight on this.

Comment: The readonly attribute can't be set on select fields though, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ASP **web controls**. The TextBox for the input type="text".
All web controls have the **enabled** property

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtSomething" runat="server" />
```

You can now enable/disable all controls from code like you do today (for the panel). But you have to do it for every one (I don´t know how many you have).

```
txtSomething.Enabled = False
```

You can also do this with JavaScript.
Loop all elements in the form, and disable/enable them.

```
function DisableEnableForm(myForm,setDisable){
  elems = myForm.elements;
  for(i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
    elems[i].disabled = setDisable;
  }
}
```

You can trigger this JavaScript function from ASP like this:

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:DisableEnableForm(´form1´,true)");
```

Comment: The issue with this is that browsers treat disabled fields differently. In IE, you can't scroll text in a text box or items in a select box.